# Latency of Components

Tags: verilog, circuit-design, hardware, adder, multiplexer

Latency comparison between the addition of dependent modules vs independent modules?

For example, a 32-bit adder made up of thirty-two 1-bit adders. Each 1-bit adder calculation depends on the previous adder for the Cin value. Thus, the adder modules in this component are dependent of each other. Obviously, adding additional dependent 1-bit adders into this component would increase the overall latency (delay from input to output) of the component.

[image]

What about a component with independent modules?

For example a 32-bit 2-to-1 MUX made up of thirty-two 1-bit 2-to-1 MUXes. Each 1-bit 2-to-1 MUX only needs 1-bit from the 32-bit inputs. Thus, the modules are independent from each other.

Would adding additional independent 1-bit 2-to-1 MUXes into this component increase the overall latency? If so, would the latency be less than equally-complex dependent modules?

[image]

Comment: sounds like you are trying to reinvent the [Carry-lookahead adder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carry-lookahead_adder)

Comment: Sounds like you need to refresh the *critical path* concept.